# Implications of $\inf_{\left\|x\right\|,\left\|y\right\|\le c}\sup_{\gamma\text{ coupling of }δ_xκ,δ_yκ}\gamma\left(\{\rho<δ\}\right)>0$

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-analysis, ergodic-theory, coupling

Let $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space, $d$ be a complete separable metric on $E$, $\delta$ denote the Dirac kernel on $(E,\mathcal B(E))$ and $\kappa$ be a Markov kernel on $(E,\mathcal B(E))$. Assume $$a:=\inf_{\substack{(x,\:y)\:\in\:E^2\\\left\|x\right\|_E,\:\left\|y\right\|_E\:\le\:c}}\sup_{\substack{\gamma\\\gamma\text{ is a coupling of }\delta_x\kappa\text{ and }\delta_y\kappa}}\gamma\left(\left\{\rho<\delta\right\}\right)>0\tag1$$ for all $c,\delta>0$.

> Let $c,\delta>0$. How can we conclude that for all $(x,y)\in E^2$ with $\left\|x\right\|_E,\left\|y\right\|_E\le c$, there is a coupling $\gamma$ of $\delta_x\kappa$ and $\delta_y\kappa$ with $$\gamma\left(\left\{\rho\le\frac\delta2\right\}\right)>a?\tag2$$

Let $(x,y)\in E^2$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Then, clearly, there is a coupling $\gamma$ of $\delta_x\kappa$ and $\delta_y\kappa$ with $$\gamma\left(\left\{\rho<\delta\right\}\right)>a-\varepsilon.\tag3$$ Maybe $\delta$ should be replaced by $\delta/2$ in $(3)$ and clearly $$\gamma\left(\left\{\rho<\delta\right\}\right)=\gamma\left(\left\{\rho\le\frac\delta2\right\}\right)+\gamma\left(\left\{\rho\in\left(\frac\delta2,\delta\right)\right\}\right),\tag4$$ but I'm not able to obtain $(2)$ from that.

Comment: The set of couplings between two probability measures should be compact for the weak topology under some appropriate conditions on $E$ ($E$ Polish I believe) so that the supremum will be attained.

Comment: @Michh Can you elaborate (and maybe giving some references) why compactness wrt weak topology (which weak topology are we talking about?) implies that the supremum is attained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assume that $E$ is Polish** so that the set of couplings between any two probability measures on $E$ is compact w.r.t. the weak topology. Here weak topology refers to the topology of weak convergence for measures, that is $\gamma_n \to \gamma$ if $\int_E f d\gamma_n \to \int_E fd\gamma$ for every continuous bounded $f \colon E \to \mathbb{R}$.

Let $x,y \in E$ and set $F = \{\rho \leq \delta \}$ (the argument requires a closed set). Since
$$\sup_{\gamma \text{ coupling of } \delta_x \kappa \text{ and } \delta_y \kappa} \gamma(F) \geq a,$$
for every $n$ there exists a coupling $\gamma_n$ such that $\gamma_n(F) \geq a-\frac{1}{n}$. By compactness we may assume that $\gamma_n$ converges weakly to some coupling $\gamma$. Then by the Portmanteau theorem we get
$$\gamma(F) \geq \limsup_n \gamma_n(F) \geq a.$$

---

For the compactness of the set of couplings, check out lemma $0.13$ and Corollary $0.14$ [here](http://home.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/ketterer/lecture_notes_metric_measure_spaces.pdf). The proof relies on the Prokhorov theorem.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the "set of couplings is compact" claim?

Comment: @0xbadf00d see the edit

Comment: (a) Please note that I've mistakenly defined $E$ to be a metric space, while the infimum in $(1)$ was taken over the closed ball around $0$ in $E^2$. So, I've intended to let $E$ be a Banach space and $d$ be any complete separable metric on $E$. Now we should need to be careful. In order for your argument to work, we should require that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(E)$ on $E$ induced by the norm on $E$ coincides with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra induced by the topology $\tau_\rho$ generated by $\rho$, right? This should be equivalent to requiring that $\tau_\rho$ coincides

Comment: with the topology generated by the norm on $E$. The next thing is that we need that $\{\rho\le\delta\}$ is $\tau_\rho$-closed; but isn't this true for any metric $\rho$? (b) Did I get you right that the result generally holds for every complete separable metric space $(E,\rho)$, Markov kernel on $(E,\mathcal B(E))$ (here $\mathcal B(E)$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the topology induced by $\rho$), $x,y\in E$ and closed $B\subseteq E^2$ satisfying $a:=\sup_\gamma\gamma[B]>0$? And all we use is that the set of those couplings is sequentially compact, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d (a) You are right, I was a bit careless there. If you assume that $\rho$ induces the same topology as the norm topology then everything works fine indeed. And the closed ball is always closed in any metric space. (b) Absolutely right, and only *sequential* compactness is needed.

Comment: I quickly correct myself: if $E$ is Polish then the space of probability measures $\mathcal{P}(E)$ endowed with the weak topology is metrizable (and Polish), so no difference between compactness and sequential compactness.

Comment: So, the point of the conclusion in (b) is that $\gamma(B)=a$ (since you've showed $\gamma(B)\ge a$ and it $\gamma(B)\le a$ is trivial from the definition, right?

Comment: BTW: You've written "the closed ball is always closed in any metric space", which is clearly correct, but $\{\rho\le\delta\}$ is not a closed ball in a metric space or am I missing something?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Oops you're obviously right! But it is still closed, for instance this is the set of points at distance at most $\delta$ from the diagonal $D= \{(x,x): \, x\in E\}\subset E^2$ where the "distance" on $E^2$ is $d((x,y),(x',y')) = \rho(x,x') + \rho(y,y')$. Maybe there is an easier way of seeing this though

Comment: Sorry for replying to this post again, but I just figured out that in my application the topology $\tau_\rho$ induced by $\rho$ is *not* equal to the topology $\tau_E$ induced by $\left\;\cdot\;\right\|_E$. However, $\tau_\rho$ is coarser than $\tau_E$. So, $\rho$ is separable (and complete? Should be trivial, but I'm unsure at the moment). Note that $\mathcal B(E,\tau_\rho)\subseteq\mathcal B(E)$. Is this a problem at some point? Do we need to take $F$ to be $\tau_\rho$-closed or $\tau_E$-closed?